# Running a Cron on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a folder in my live directory (`/var/www`), called cron.
How do I configure the server to find this directory, in order to execute the files using a cron.

I need to run certain scripts at different intervals. e.g. 2-3 Files everyday, and 1-2 files every Wednesday.

What would I need to put in the crontab in order do the above? I've attempted to add `* * * * * /var/www/email.php` as a text, which should send me an email every minutes, but nothing comes through.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to see /var/log/syslog to check for error messages ? Do you have access to the server as root ? Maybe the cron service is not running...

Comment: It says it failed with exit status 2?

Comment: exit status 2 usually is ENOENT i.e. 'no such file or directory'. Cron probably wasn't able to read its file.

Answer (score 1):

try it this way:

```
* * * * * php -q /var/www/email.php
```

also make sure the file is executable as the user you run the cronjob as

Comment: Do I put that code in the crontab file? How do I check the file is executable as the user I am running the cronjob as?

Comment: @user826855:  If you have to ask something as basic as that then you shouldn't be doing any of this.

Comment: edited code to show it as an example cron line based on your info provided, but plus 1 on Iain, be very careful if you dont know what your doing

Comment: @Iain Everybody has to start somewhere, plus I'm on a testing server, so it mistakes don't really matter.

Comment: @user826855: [faq]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the location of a users crontab file. They are usually located  `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>` Why do you want to place a crontab in `/var/www/cron` ?

Does `email.php` contain a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line at the top `#!/usr/bin/php` (or similar) if is doesn't then you should add one.

If email.php does have a shebang ensure that it is executable by the user who is running it.

Is cron running ?

```
ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep
root      4148     1  0 Aug04 ?        00:00:00 crond
```

if not start it.

Comment: I don't want to place a crontab in "/var/www" I just want to execute some files as a cron that are located in "/var/www".

What does "#!/usr/bin/php" do?